# WebUSB: How to call navigator.usb.requestDevice() if navigator.usb.getDevices() fails

Tags: javascript, promise, usb, webusb

I am writing a WebUSB based extension for Scratch3. In the extensions constructor i need to establish the WebUSB connection. Ideally i'd like to use navigator.usb.getDevices() to check for available/paired devices and if that fails i'd like to ask the user to select a device using navigator.usb.requestDevice().

The problem is that navigator.usb.requestDevice() needs to be called from a user gesture. In most cases the scratch3 extension constructor is being called from a user action and thus I can use navigator.usb.requestDevice() just fine.

But navigator.usb.getDevices() returns a Promise and invoking navigator.usb.requestDevice() from there fails with
"Must be handling a user gesture to show a permission request."

So the following works (but opens a request dialog every single time):

```
navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId: 0x2341 }] })
        .then(selectedDevice => {
            // ...
        })
```

But the following fails due to missing "user gesture":

```
navigator.usb.getDevices().then(devices => {
    if(devices.length == 0) {
        navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId: 0x2341 }] })
            .then(selectedDevice => {
                // ...
        })
    }
})
```

I'd like to avoid messing with the Scratch 3 core and thus don't want to add another UI element.

Using only navigator.usb.requestDevice() as in the first snippet has two major disadvantages:

1. It opens the request dialog all the time although it's only necessary once
2. Sometimes later the constructor may be called from a non-interactive situation and navigator.usb.requestDevice() would completely fail while navigator.usb.getDevices() would succeed

Is there a way to make the approach from the second code snippet work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Scratch 3 but is it possible to call `getDevices()` when your extension is initialized and defer providing a button the user can click to trigger `requestDevice()` until after the code knows whether it already has permission to access a device?

The `getDevices()` method, and `onconnect` and `ondisconnect` event handlers are provided so that the page can keep its interface up to date with any available devices.

Comment: As i wrote:

`I'd like to avoid messing with the Scratch 3 core and thus don't want to add another UI element.`

Messing with the UI and/or the core basically nullifies the chances of being able to run the extension with a regular scratch3 version.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed as of Chrome 72 through the [User Activation v2](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5722065667620864) feature.